# ios keep subview on top when scrolling

Tags: ios, ios6, scroll

I have a `UITableViewController`. In the `UITableView` I have a subview - `ImageView`. `ImageView` this is my header of `TableView`. I want that header (`ImageView`) is always on top when I scroll.

I have the following code which work on IOS 5, but does not work on IOS 6:

```
- (Void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) scrollView {
[ImageView setFrame: CGRectMake (0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y, 320, 100)];
}
```

So, what should I do to solve this problem on IOS 6?

Comment: certainly looks like it should work. what's the behavior you see?

Comment: Why not take the imageView out of the table and put it above it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header and footer in `UITableView` and `UICollection` view are fixed inside there `container scrollview`. What you need to do is actually place a button outside of your `UITableViewController` and added after that controller either in Interface builder or when setting up your VC in `viewDidload`. This will then be above the scroll view. You might want to resize the `UITableViewController` so that the content doesnt pass under the button.